# how to store returned video capture devices

Tags: silverlight

> I am making silverlight application in which i have to show multiple webcams videos. 
>   For example:

- if i click button:1 then it show me fist webcam video and  if i click
- button: 2 then it show me second wecam video.

> As 'CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableVideoCaptureDevices()' returns us all available video devices but problem is this that how i store each returned webcam device in variable so that I can perform the above mentioned task?